# Find the general term of the recursive relation $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k 2^{2n-2k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I need to find the general term of the recursive relation $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k 2^{2n-2k+1}$
I know it's the central binomial sequence but I can't find a way to show it.

$a_0=1$

Comment: This seems taylored for the generating series $A(x)=\sum\limits_na_nx^n$. Did you try to identify $A(x)$?

Comment: the only thing i managed to do is say that $A'(x)=2F(x)G(x)$ where $G(x)=1+2x+4x^2+6x^3...$

Comment: You probably mean $A'(x)=2A(x)G(x)$ where $G(x)=1+2x+4x^2+8x^3+16x^4+\ldots$ hence $G(x)=$ $____$ and one gets a first order differential equation in $A$, which one can solve.

Comment: @Did Did you intend that pun?  Tailored for Taylor series? :)

Answer (score 2):

We are given the recurrence relation

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}2^{2n-2k+1}.$$

Then,

$$a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k}2^{2n-2k-1}.$$

Multiplying the relation for $a_n$ on both sides by $\frac{2^2n}{n+1}$,

$$\frac{2^2n}{n+1}a_{n}=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k}2^{2n-2k+1}.$$

Subtracting this from the original recurrence relation, we get

$$a_{n+1}-\frac{2^2n}{n+1}a_{n} = \frac{1}{n+1}a_{n}2^{2n-2n+1} = \frac{2\,a_{n}}{n+1}\\
\implies a_{n+1} = \frac{2(2n-1)}{n+1}a_{n}.$$

Now we have a simple linear recurrence relation which may be solved by more familiar methods.

Comment: The last coefficient should be $a_{n+1} = \frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1} a_n$. Personally, I will prefer to write it as $\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}$ which makes the final expression of $a_n$ more obvious.

Comment: How do you get the general term from $a_{n+1} = \frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}a_{n}$ ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon 
$$a_n = a_0 \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{a_{k}}{a_{k-1}} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k(2k-1)}{k^2} = \frac{2n!}{n!^2} = \binom{2n}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use generating functions. Define:
$$
A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
$$
Write:
$$
(n + 1) a_{n + 1} = 2 \sum_{0 \le k \le n} a_k 4^{n - k}
$$
Note that the right hand side is the convolution of $4^n$ with $a_n$. Using properties of ordinary generating functions this gives:
$$
(z \mathrm{D} + 1) \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} = 2 \frac{A(z)}{1 - 4 z}
$$
This is a first order linear differential equation ($\mathrm{D}$ is derivative), but it has an ugly solution...

**Update:** I made a mistake in the original, the correct ODE has a pleasant solution:
\begin{align}
A(z) &= (1 - 4 z)^{-1/2} \\
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{2n}{n} z^n
\end{align}
so that:
$$
a_n = \binom{2 n}{n}
$$

Comment: @achillehui, fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the solution just $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4x}}$?

Comment: Ugly? I disagree.

Comment: @Did, I made a mistake, the (wrong) ODE had a horrible solution.